# Fix hardcoded dynamic linking for executable

Tags: linux, libraries, dynamic-linking, shared-library

I have an executable file called *reg* with the following shared library dependencies:

```
[terminal]$ ldd ./reg
linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007ffc40d90000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000003be0c00000)
/usr/dep/packages/opt/intel/mkl/10.0.2.018/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_lp64.so => not found
```

When executing the binary I get the following:

```
[terminal]$ ./reg
./reg: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/dep/packages/opt/intel/mkl/10.0.2.018/lib/em64t/libmkl_intel_lp64.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

The thing is that I don't have the administrative rights to create the specified directory path and place the library there. Moreover, I don't have the source code so I can't re-compile it either but I do have *libmkl_intel_lp64.so* library stored somewhere else. I tried using *LD_PRELOAD* environment variable but it still needs that library in that specific location. Is there a solution how could I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `fakeroot`, not sure if it will work, if not, talk with the sysadmin.

Comment: Maybe `patchelf` could help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't have the same binary you have but I made a little test and it
seems that `patchelf` can work here.  I have a `hello` binary compiled
with `-Wl,-rpath=/home/ja/c/hello-puts/make/lib` and `libtest.so` as a
dependency:

```
$ ldd hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffedb4f0000)
        libtest.so => /home/ja/c/hello-puts/make/lib/libtest.so (0x00007f04a2437000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f04a200f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000564a42e36000)
```

I run `patchelf` with `--make-needed-absolute` using `patchelf` from https://github.com/dezgeg/patchelf/:

```
$ patchelf --make-needed-absolute hello
$ ldd hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff9baa3000)
        /home/ja/c/hello-puts/make/lib/libtest.so (0x00007f81bd0e2000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f81bccba000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556714bb5000)
```

I think that's what you have.  I copied `hello` to other machine and:

```
$ ldd ./hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff92e7d000)
        /home/ja/c/hello-puts/make/lib/libtest.so => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff381c9b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff382065000)
```

I first removed a needed `libtest.so` dependency:

```
$ patchelf --remove-needed /home/ja/c/hello-puts/make/lib/libtest.so hello
$ ldd hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffdcedfb000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f60705c5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f607098f000)
```

I tried to run `hello`, it started but due to lazy binding done by the
interpreter only the first line of the expected output was shown:

```
$ ./hello
hello world
./hello: symbol lookup error: ./hello: undefined symbol: foo
```

I added `libtest.so` again but without an absolute path:

```
$ patchelf --add-needed libtest.so hello
$ ldd hello
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffda155c000)
        libtest.so => not found
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffbdb8c3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffbdbc8d000)
```

I copied `libtest.so` to `$PWD` and was able to start `hello`:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./hello
hello world
inside foo()
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning patchelf, quite interesting.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Arkadiusz Drabczyk! Exactly what I needed and works like a charm! Appreciate that!